# How to run simple java file with docker

Tags: java, docker

I am extremely new to the world of docker. I am trying to learn on the most basic example in Java. I have a project folder called docker-java, and a Dockerfile inside along with a Hello.java file that souts out hello.
I am trying to build the image so I may run it and see the output in the terminal. Here is my dockerfile. I am being told Hello.java can not be found.

```
FROM java

RUN javac Hello.java

CMD java Hello
```

Comment: You have to copy the Hello.java file to your container. Something like COPY Hello.java .

Comment: Hello. There's a complete documentation about how to work with Java and Docker on official Docker website : https://github.com/docker/labs/tree/master/developer-tools/java/

Comment: @LongNguyen Would it be copy ./ Hello.java ? Is it a relative path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code to copy your Hello.java (I assume the java file is in the same folder as your dockerfile)

```
FROM java

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/your_workdir

WORKDIR /usr/src/your_workdir

COPY Hello.java ./

RUN javac Hello.java

CMD java Hello
```

You basicly have to copy your java file into your container. It is also recommended to create a personal workdir to avoid possible conflict with native files.

Comment: Thanks a lot this did the trick. Is it convention to also run the mkdir and workdir commands in your docker file every time? Thanks!